# rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, scaffold

Whilst doing https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app tutorial in section 2.2 where I had to write: `$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`, I got some errors:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from c:/Users/User/desktop/web/workspace/toy_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions? It has been bugging me whole day

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Rails 4.2.0beta and above have a dependency on the `pty` gem and it is unable to find it.

```
`require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
```

This is due to the fact that this gem is not yet available on Windows. For a temporary fix you can remove the `web-console` gem from your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` after removing that gem.